# postgres database not available over network

Tags: database, postgresql, networking, psql

So I have changed the postgresql.conf file to this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
```

port = 5432             # (change requires restart)

Then I changed the pg_hba.conf to `host all all 127.0.0.1/32` and `host all all 2601:643:8402:f900:1045:d5ae:1d3b:19d1`
But I when I enter `show listen_addresses;` It still only lists local host. What do I need to fix in order to access my databases over a local network?

Answer (score 0):

After changing those files you need to restart the database.

Comment: I restarted the database using: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast` and the started it again `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start` but I still get `local host` host for the listen_address.